# Plotting the hours of the day instead of time

Tags: python, matplotlib

title probably does not make sense, but I will try to explain.

I am plotting chemical concentrations overtime. The x axis should be hours since midnight local time (i.e., 0,4,8,12,16,20). However, when I do this all of the xticks get smushed together to to left.

```
xticks = range(0,24,4)
ozoneest["mean"].plot(ax=ax, xticks=xticks,)
```

Results in:

[image]

xticks is only accepting arrays of datetime variables, which have values: 00:00, 04:00, 08:00, 12:00, 16:00, 20:00.

```
xticks = pd.date_range("2000/01/01", end="2000/01/02", freq="4H").time
ozoneest["mean"].plot(ax=ax, xticks=xticks,)
```

results in:

[image]

This is close to what I want, but I want just the number of the hour

Thanks!

Comment: How many values do you have to plot ? If you have more than 6 values, then you have to "merge" them to get only the 6 values needed for the plot. Maybe you have 100 measures overtime, with 15 values between 00h and 4h00 etc...

Comment: @Gaston there are 24 measurements being plotted. I do not want every hour along the x axis though. Thanks!

Comment: The structure that contains the data is a simple list with 24 values then ?

Comment: @Gaston it is a series, from a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your data is stored in a pandas dataframe with a DatetimeIndex that has an "Hour" frequency. I cannot exactly reproduce your problem seeing as you have not shared the code generating the `ax` object. Whether it is created with matplotlib or pandas, the problem is that the x-axis unit is based on the number of time periods (based on the DatetimeIndex frequency in pandas, days in matplotlib) that have passed since 1970-01-01. So the `xticks = range(0,24,4)` land far to the left relative to your datetimes. You can check the x-axis values of the default xticks with `ax.get_xticks()`.

Here are two ways of formatting the xticks and labels as you want. I suggest that you do not create a new DatetimeIndex for the hours as this makes the code less easy to reuse, use instead the DatetimeIndex of the dataframe as shown in the second solution.

**Create sample dataframe**

```py
import numpy as np   # v 1.20.2
import pandas as pd  # v 1.2.5

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=123)  # random number generator
time = pd.date_range(start="2000/01/01", end="2000/01/02", freq="H")[:-1]
mean = rng.normal(size=len(time))
ozoneest = pd.DataFrame(dict(mean=mean), index=time)
ozoneest.head()
```

[image: df_head]

**Pandas plot with default xticks**

```py
ozoneest["mean"].plot()
```

[image: plot]

**Simple solution: do not use the DatetimeIndex as the x-axis**

```py
xticks = range(0,24,4)
ax = ozoneest["mean"].plot(use_index=False, xticks=xticks)
```

[image: custom_xticks_range]

**General solution: select xticks from DatetimeIndex and create labels with [strftime](https://strftime.org/)**

```py
xticks = ozoneest.index[::4]
xticklabels = xticks.strftime("%H")
ax = ozoneest["mean"].plot()
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticks([], minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(xticklabels)
```

[image: custom_xticks_strftime]

This solution is more general because you do not need to manually adjust the xticks if the range of time of your dataset changes and the tick labels can be easily customized in many ways.
If you want to remove the leading zeros, you can use the following list comprehension:

```py
xticklabels = [tick[1:] if tick[0] == "0" else tick for tick in xticks.strftime("%H")]
```